# Transparent material

Tags: materials, transparency

I have selected a section of tyre and uv unwrapped that section so that i can add a logo.
Saved the logo as png with transparency.
Set to alpha clip and put the node on alpha.
When i render i get a dark patch where it is supposed to be transparent.
What causes that?
And is this the best way to add logos?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to make a transparent shader here, you don't want light to go through your surface. What you want is to layer you logo on top of the existing color data that are then used into your shader.

Whatever makes your shader's color data, you should mix that with your texture node using a Mix node and using your texture's alpha output as the factor.

For example:

[image: example setup]

Comment: Ok, so to add a logo to a specific area of the tyre. I make a new material in the area i want. Unwrap. Export UV. Add logo. Save as PNG. Use that node set up?

Comment: Don't use a new material, you can't stack materials.

Comment: Ok, so what is the best way to add a logo to that tyre? i have tried shrink wrapping and that doesnt bring great results either.

Comment: Have you tried what I show in my answer? Just use your existing tire's material and mix in your logo with the base color data of that material. Use a different UV map for that texture if you want, but that's about it.

Comment: So how do you make a new uv without assigning a material?

Comment: You don't need a different material to make a different uv to begin with. Any material uses the active UV of your object, but you can use a UV Map node in your material to manually select any UV map on your object.